# Trying to find a shared library using CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to find the avformat library for my project using CMake. My first option was to use a `FIND_PACKAGE(...)` but I couldn't find any CMake Module for it in $CMAKE_ROOT/Modules. Now I'm trying to find it using `FIND_LIBRARY(...)`.

The library is in `/usr/lib/libavformat.so.52`.

This is my CMake code for finding it:

```
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat PATHS /usr/lib DOC "avformat library")
if(NOT AVFORMAT_LIBRARY)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Library avformat required, but not found!")
endif(NOT AVFORMAT_LIBRARY)
```

However, I can't find it. Why do you think that is?

I could type the specific library name (i.e. `libavformat.so.52`), but that would tie the code to that specific version, which I wouldn't want.

EDIT: I just tried typing the exact library name `libavformat.so.52` and that didn't work either. :S

What are your suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what the problem was.

If you do a search for 'avformat' in aptitude/synaptic you get a couple results but no libavformat-dev. So I thought there was none! However, if you search for 'libavformat' then the library appears! I swear I thought that aptitude/synaptic did a regular expression search, not just for the beginning. -.-

Now it all works! :D